# how to clear the password in angular2

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsHov.png)here i upload my html and ts page.The logic of this code is when we click the delete button for delete operation one pop up message will be shown there we want to enter the password to delete that particular field,where i faced one issue when i am clicked the button to delete the particular field it get deleted but again the same password is shown for going to delete the another field.Kindly give me a proper solution to solve this.Thank You.

```
        HTML
        <button type="button"
                                            class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm icmn-bin" 
                                            data-toggle="modal" data-name="{{source_info.source.name}}"  
                                            [attr.data-target]="'#delete_modal_' + source_info.source.name"  (click)="clear()"
                                            *ngIf="source_info.source.assigned ===  false"></button>  


    <!--  bootstrap modal starts -->
                                    <div class="modal fade modal-size-small delete-modal" id="delete_modal_{{source_info.source.name}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are You Sure to
                                                        Delete ?</h5>
                                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <h6>Enter Your password to confirm Delete <strong>{{source_info.source.name}}</strong></h6>
                                                                <input class="form-control input-pos" name="password" 
                                                                    [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group pull-right">
                                                            <!--    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                                    type="button">Cancel</button>  -->
                                                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                                                                    (click)="name=source_info.source.name;deleteSource(name, password)">Delete</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--  bootstrap modal ends -->

TS
  deleteSource(name, password) {
    const headers = new Headers({'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('Token'), 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    console.log(name, password);

    $('.delete-modal').modal('hide');
    if (password === localStorage.getItem('Password')) {
      this.service.delete(options, services.data_source_service + name).subscribe((response) => {
        this.message.handle('icmn-checkmark', '', 'Data source has been deleted', 'success');
        this.getSources();
      }, (err) => {
        this.message.errorHandler(err);
      })
    } else {
      this.password = '';
      $.notify({
        message: 'Password not valid for delete operation!'
      },
        {
          type: 'warning'
        })
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can probably set your password to an empty string inside `this.service.delete(...).subscribe(...)`, just like this `this.password = '';`, so that when the deletion is successfull it is resetted to an empty string

Comment: Being a fresher i don't know how to write a code for this.Can u please change the above code with correct format what we need.Actually i did what you have said but it is not working in mobile view in all devices can you give some solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to enter a password in a modal to clear a datasource. After entering the password and deleting the datasource, the password field should be empty again so you have to enter it again on the next delete, but if you enter it once it will stay in the field and won't be cleared after the delete action.

The solution is adding just one line of code inside your `.ts` file. When the delete action is successful you have to set the password back to an empty string. This must be done inside of the `subscribe` function.

```
if (password === localStorage.getItem('Password')) {
  this.service.delete(options, services.data_source_service + name).subscribe((response) => {
    this.message.handle('icmn-checkmark', '', 'Data source has been deleted', 'success');
    this.getSources();

    // SET PASSWORD TO EMPTY STRING HERE
    this.password = '';
  }, (err) => {
    this.message.errorHandler(err);
  })
} else {
  this.password = '';
  $.notify({
    message: 'Password not valid for delete operation!'
  },
    {
      type: 'warning'
    })
}
```

After every succesful deletion the password field should be empty again when trying to delete the next data.

### EDIT - clear password on close

Now when we close the modal without pressing the button, the password field will still be filled. So we have to do the same thing when we press the close button. We can add a function to this button that will be executed when pressed.

```
<button data-dismiss="modal" type="button" (click)="onModalClose()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

In our typescript file we now have just clear the password again inside of this function.

```
onModalClose(){
    this.password='';
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if this function will override the dismiss function, but I think it should do both, the closing of the modal and executing `onModalClose`

Comment: I have send you my screenshot.Your idea is suited for desktop view but it is not working in mobile view in all the devices

Comment: without any further information, I can't help you, I'm sorry. Angular does not care about mobile or desktop view, if you code something this simple like setting a string to an empty value, it should work for both, unless there is something else going on. Is there anything different at your code between mobile and desktop views, any code that is executed only for one?

Comment: Also are you sure this only happens when you press the delete button? for example your password will probably be still entered when you just close the modal without deleting

Comment: password will probably be still entered when you just close the modal without deleting,yes this one is our problem but it is not working in mobile view in data table list view

Comment: Actually here we are using a jquery data table. whether due to using this jquery our problem is not solved in mobile view?

Comment: yes that is probably the case, do you have any code for that?

Comment: the code in the question is the jquery data table code for the mobile view?

Comment: There is no separate code for  data table mobile view we are using the same code for both desktop and mobile view  data table.

Comment: can you debug the code in the mobile view, set a breakpoint inside your `subscribe` function and check if it is executed? or is the problem **only** at closing the modal, but not at pressing the delete button anymore? so which problem are we currently trying to solve here?

Comment: the problem only at closing the modal, but not at pressing the delete button anymore is the issue

Comment: yes genius ....tq so much it will take 2 weeks to fix that issue but now it is fixed ...very happy .. plz help like this for others .. once again tq